String matches method - forward slash not working
I am trying to match file paths of the following pattern:
/Users/someuser/folder/folder/config/server1/overlay.properties
I am using the following code to walk through the files in a path and match files of the above pattern:
String SOURCE_CONFIG_PATH = "/Users/someuser/folder/folder/config";

Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCE_CONFIG_PATH))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .filter(file -> file.getFileName().toString().matches(".*/overlay\\.properties$"))
                .forEach(file -> {System.out.println(file.toString());});

This does not match the files, but the following code does:
filter(file -> file.getFileName().toString().matches(".*overlay\\.properties$"))

which would also pick /Users/someuser/folder/folder/config/server1/shouldnotmatchoverlay.properties
Have tried escaping / resulting in ".*\\/overlay\\.properties$" and ".*\\\\/overlay\\.properties$" which has not solved the issue.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName() getFileName() returns... the file name, i.e. overlay.properties.

@DawoodibnKareem Done.

Lesson learned: read the code generated by copilot. :)

The getFileName() method, rather unsurprisingly, returns only the file name, not the complete path. As defined by the Javadoc:

The file name is the farthest element from the root in the directory
hierarchy.

For the given path of /Users/someuser/folder/folder/config/server1/overlay.properties, the file name is overlay.properties. If you just need to match files with that file name, regardless of their path, you don't need any regular expressions and can just use equals():
filter(file -> file.getFileName().toString().equals("overlay.properties"))

